# How to write script to download spreadsheet?

Tags: download, spreadsheet, yahoo-finance

Yahoo Finance provides spreadsheets of historical data for every symbol. But I don't want to download each of them manually. Is there any way I can write a script to download all of them? For example, I have a list of symbols in a file. I'd like the script to go through the file, and download the spreadsheet for that symbol in a specified directory.

Edit: I'm on OSX 10.8.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple http get on the download link worked.

Answer (score 0):

If your OS is linux based just do

wget "download path1"

**Read more here**

http://www.simplehelp.net/2008/12/11/how-to-download-files-from-the-linux-command-line/

If you are using Windows :

**Follow this**

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/files-from-websites-4a181ff3